# Custom JButton with Graphics for a Calculator Implementation

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton

I'm trying to program a **Calculator** as close to the **Windows 7/8** model as possible, and I'm currently trying to give the `Jbutton`s a custom look, but it's not going as planned.My button is called `CalculatorButton` which extends `JButton`. I'm currently using `Graphics` to draw borders and make it rounder than the standard `JButton` borders, but it only seems to work for one `CalculatorButton` instance, and not subsequently created ones.

Also please excuse the bad formatting, it's my first post.

below is the calculatorbutton class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class CalculatorButton extends JButton {

    CalculatorButton() {
        super();
        this.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI",Font.PLAIN,12));
        this.setOpaque(false);
        this.setFocusPainted(false);
    }

    CalculatorButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        this.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI",Font.PLAIN,12));
        this.setOpaque(false);
        this.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(144,158,171));
        g.drawLine(getX()+1,getY(),getX()+getWidth()-2,getY());
        g.drawLine(getX()+1,getY()+getHeight()-1,getX()+getWidth()-2,getY()+getHeight()-1);
        g.drawLine(getX(),getY()+1,getX(),getY()+getHeight()-2);
        g.drawLine(getX()+getWidth()-1,getY()+1,getX()+getWidth()-1,getY()+getHeight()-2);
    }   
}
```

below is the calculator class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    /***************************************/ //aesthetics like font,color,icons,etc
    private Color backgroundColor = new Color(218,229,240);

    /**************************************/ //menubar
    /*************************************///textfield
    private JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
    /*************************************/
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    /*************************************/
    /*************************************/

    Calculator() {
        super("Calculator");
        setSize(400,320);
        setResizable(false);
        this.add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        mainPanel.add(textPanel);
        textPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textPanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        CalculatorButton c = new CalculatorButton("1");
        CalculatorButton cb = new CalculatorButton("w");
        textPanel.add(c);
        textPanel.add(cb);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception {
        //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        calc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `setOpaque(true/false)` using setContentAreaFilled(true/false)` will suffice, as noted in the [Java Docs API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled-boolean-)

Comment: try your success by WindowsClassicsLookAndFeel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, all painting is done within a local context.  That is, the `Graphics` context is translated to the components location (x/y).

This means that the top/left corner is actually `0x0` and the bottom/right corner is `width - 1 x height - 1`

Second of all, instead of overriding `paintBorder`, you should consider making your own `Border` which meets your needs.  Borders don't just paint, they also provide important information about the additional space they need

Answer (score 2):

Extend the [BasicButtonUI class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonUI.html).

See examples such as [this.](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/11/rounded-corner-jbutton.html)

But there is a better way, use the [css styling of JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/css.htm#BEIBBBCI)